# Detect if user install application from AppInvite Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I need to detect at first launch if user install application from Facebook AppInvite.
So when user send AppInvite I use generated by Facebook Link Hosting API link, for example: fb.me/12243432423

Is it right to do next verify:

```
Uri targetUrl = AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(PreloaderActivity.this, getIntent());
if (targetUrl != null) {
   //install from invite
} else {
   //install not from invite
}
```

Or it's mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Facebook Ad SDK to track the install from Facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/sdk

Comment: Thank you. So I need to use Deferred Deep Link? Or I can use other method? Because fetchDeferredAppLinkData asynchronously and there is not listener for finish.

Comment: That SDK basically tracks the install comes from Facebook Ad. Its so simple to integrate. Just follow the documentation

Comment: I need not only track. I need to detect it. In documentation says about asynchronously method for fetch deferred AppLink.

Comment: And whats wrong with your code? I feel like your code works. Just do it your Main activity. I mean starting activity